# Create and configure a CDN from Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, cdn, powershell-cmdlet, azure-cdn

I have a powershell script that must setup all my infrastructure with a single click, what I'm missing is a way to create and configure the CDN, this seems to be only possible from the management portal.

Thanks

Comment: Did you search on technet for any assistance?

Comment: @user4317867 Yes, I've searched technet, msdn, the new azure documentation but found nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-create-new-endpoint/#comment-2138332717) creating a CDN endpoint through Azure PowerShell is not supported yet.

Quoting the link's Q&A:

> Q: [ViewRidge] How can I create a CDN endpoint using Azure PowerShell?
>
> A: [Manling] -> [ViewRidge] We don't support it today but it's targeted to be
>   supported in CY Q4.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just edited the answer accordingly.